# Por que não entra no loop das notas?

Tags: c, loop

Estou armazenando nome e notas de alunos e tentando exibir o nome, as notas e a média. O problema é que o programa está pulando o loop das notas e só está pegando o nome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*
Síntese
Objetivo: Calcular a média das notas de um aluno
Entrada: Nome, Nota 1, nota 2, nota 3, e nota 4
Saída: Nome, notas do aluno e média
*/


#define MAX_NOME 100
#define MAX_NOTAS 4
#define VETOR_MAX 50
typedef struct Alunos{
    char nome[MAX_NOME];
    int notas[MAX_NOTAS];
}Aluno;

int leValidaOpcao();
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int cont=0, cont2=0, qtdAlunos=0, soma;
    char continuar = ' ';
    float media=0.0;

    Aluno * aluno1 = malloc(qtdAlunos * sizeof(Aluno));


    do{
        printf("Informe o %d%c nome :", cont+1, 167);
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", (aluno1+cont)->nome);

        for(cont2; cont2 < MAX_NOTAS;cont2++){
            printf("Informe a nota %d:", cont2+1);
            scanf("%d", &(aluno1+cont)->notas[cont2]);
            soma += (aluno1+cont)-> notas[cont2];
            system("cls");
        }

        printf("Nome = %s\n", (aluno1+cont)->nome);
        for(cont2; cont2 < MAX_NOTAS; cont2++){
            printf("Nota[%d] =  %d\n", cont2+1, (aluno1+cont)->notas[cont2]);
        }
        printf("\nMedia = %f", soma/MAX_NOTAS);

        continuar = leValidaOpcao();
        cont++;
    }while(continuar == 's' && cont < VETOR_MAX);


    free(aluno1);
    return 0;
}
int leValidaOpcao(){
    char opcao = ' ';
    int flag = 1;


    do{
        printf("Deseja continuar (S - sim ou Nao - N)");
        scanf(" %c", &opcao);
        opcao = tolower(opcao);

        if(opcao != 's' && opcao != 'n'){
            printf("\nOpcao invalida!\n");
            flag = 0;
        }
    }while(!flag);
    return opcao;
}
```

Comment: no `for` é preciso colocar `cont2=0`, basta fazer um mini debug para descobrir essa falha

Comment: Verdade, Fábio. Só que tá aparecendo lixo.

Comment: Descobri o erro. É na formatação dos dados.

Comment: Achei que havia descoberto, mas me enganei. Continua dando problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é utilizar a mesma variável `cont2` nos dois loops.

```
    for(cont2; cont2 < MAX_NOTAS;cont2++){
        printf("Informe a nota %d:", cont2+1);
        scanf("%d", &(aluno1+cont)->notas[cont2]);
        soma += (aluno1+cont)-> notas[cont2];
        system("cls");
    }

    printf("Nome = %s\n", (aluno1+cont)->nome);

    for(cont2; cont2 < MAX_NOTAS; cont2++){
        printf("Nota[%d] =  %d\n", cont2+1, (aluno1+cont)->notas[cont2]);
    }
    printf("\nMedia = %f", soma/MAX_NOTAS);
```

Por você inicializar não atribuir o valor 0 à variável após o primeiro loop, ela vai começar o segundo loop com o valor final do primeiro loop, ou seja, MAX_NOTAS - 1.

Para resolver esse problema, você pode utilizar variáveis diferentes em cada loop ou inicializar a variável `cont2` novamente, por exemplo:

```
for(cont2; cont2 < MAX_NOTAS;cont2++){
    printf("Informe a nota %d:", cont2+1);
    scanf("%d", &(aluno1+cont)->notas[cont2]);
    soma += (aluno1+cont)-> notas[cont2];
    system("cls");
}

printf("Nome = %s\n", (aluno1+cont)->nome);

cont2 = 0;

for(cont2; cont2 < MAX_NOTAS; cont2++){
    printf("Nota[%d] =  %d\n", cont2+1, (aluno1+cont)->notas[cont2]);
}
printf("\nMedia = %f", soma/MAX_NOTAS);
```

Comment: Valeu, Marcelo. Eu consegui. Tinha outros erros também , mas já foram corrigidos.

Comment: De nada! Observei também que o cálculo da média não estava funcionando, não sei se você ja corrigiu esse erro também.

Comment: Mais simples e intuitivo seria fazer a atribuição a `0` dentro do `for` que é basicamente o propósito do primeiro bloco do `for`